# Link to answer in exercise package

Tags: exercises

i am creating an exercise book using the exercise package.

i understand that i can add a label to a question to link an answer to a specific question.

however, i'd like to add a link to the answer under the question. so it looks something like:

Current tex source:

```
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}
\begin{Exercise}
What is the value of 2+5?
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
7
\end{Answer}
<rest of the document>
\shipoutaAnswer
```

Current output:

```
Exercise 1: What is the value of 2 + 5?

<rest of the document>

Solution 1: 7
```

Desired output:

```
Exercise 1: What is the value of 2 + 5?
<Link to Solution at the end of the document>

<rest of the document>

Solution 1: 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exercise` package has a specific way to manage the label.

See the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf) subsection 2.4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Exercise}[label={mylabel}]
        What is the value of 2+5? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
        7
    \end{Answer}

    rest of the document
    \newpage % I've added a new page only to clearly show the hyperlink. Of course, you don't need it in your document.

    \shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @CarLaTeX :) Is there a way to achieve this if I don't want to label each exercise manually.

Comment: can someone help me with the follow-up question posted at the following link, please? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380095/exercises-with-links-to-answers-problem-using-counter

Comment: @gauravgupta Thank you for accepting my answer! I'll try to help you with your new question, too.

Comment: @gauravgupta I've already got an answer, Troy's been faster than me :)

Comment: yupp - saw Troy's answer. You two are fantastic! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
    Some introductory text.
    \Question The first question
\end{Exercise}

See the answer \hyperref[one]{here}.
\newpage
\begin{Answer}[ref=first]
    The answer to question~\ref{first}.\label{one}
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```