# Exercises with links to answers (problem using counter)

Tags: exercises

Sorry, website won't allow me to ask detailed questions as a comment (neither does it show the formatting toolbar) so adding a new question.

Problem: Trying to create an exercise list (with links to corresponding answers). all answers at end of document. However, I don't want to manually label each question. So, I thought I'll use the question number as the label, but apparently it uses the total number of questions as the label instead. Any help appreciated. Thanks to @CarLaTeX for answering the original question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379946/link-to-answer-in-exercise-package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exercise}[label={exerciseNumber}]
        What is the value of 2+5? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
        7
    \end{Answer}

    \begin{Exercise}[label={exerciseNumber}]
        What is the value of 4-1? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
        3
    \end{Answer}

     \begin{Exercise}[label={exerciseNumber}]
        What is the value of 2*4? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
        8
    \end{Answer}
    \shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

Output (incorrect):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'question number' that you are seeking for is stored as a counter, appropriately named as `Exercise` (at least, for the Exercise environment). 
You can access the counter by using:

```
\the\value{Exercise}
```

So all you need to do is to use this as a label when passing it as an option in `\begin{Exercise}`. See below for an example.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Exercise}[label={\the\value{Exercise}}]
    What is the value of $2+5$? (To see the answer click here:~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
  \end{Exercise}
  \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
    7
  \end{Answer}

  \begin{Exercise}[label={\the\value{Exercise}}]
    What is the value of $4-1$? (To see the answer click here:~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
  \end{Exercise}
  \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
    3
  \end{Answer}

  \begin{Exercise}[label={\the\value{Exercise}}]
    What is the value of $2\times 4$? (To see the answer click here:~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
  \end{Exercise}
  \begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
    8
  \end{Answer}
  \shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

> [image: Ex v2]

---

### Additional information

You can perhaps make it less cumbersome to type the label, if

**(Option 1)** you define a macro like `\blah`:

```
% Preamble:    
\newcommand*{\blah}{\the\value{Exercise}}
% Main document:
\begin{Exercise}[label=\blah]
```

or

**(Option 2)** if you're feeling extra lazy, just simply define a new environment:

```
% In Preamble
\newcounter{Ex}
\newenvironment{Ex}{\begin{Exercise}[name={Exercise},
    counter={Ex},
    label=\the\value{Ex}]}
{\end{Exercise}}
```

and then in the main document, call your exercises like so:

```
% In Main document
\begin{Ex}
    What is the value of $2+5$? (To see the answer click here:~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\end{Ex}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
    7
\end{Answer}
```

Comment: Troy and @CarLaTeX - you guys are absolute legends! Amazing! Thanks a tonne and then some more :)

Comment: Hi everyone. Is it possible to active the hyperlink `\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}` if and only if the answer is non empty ? (else I would like to hide the message (To see the answer cli ...)).