# how get hyperlink problems to answer in arabic

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref, labels, arabic

How can I get hyperlink between exercise and his answer in arabic model
for exemple make this model to arabic
or any model  Through which I write in Arabic to get hyperlink between exercise and his answer

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}


\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linkcolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcounter{Answer}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\arabic{Exercise}}
\newcounter{myexerciselabel}
\newcounter{myexercisenumber}[chapter]
 %
\newenvironment{exo}[2][\unskip]{\stepcounter{myexerciselabel}\stepcounter{myexercisenumber}
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{myexerciselabel}}, number= 
{\the\value{myexercisenumber}}, counter={myexercisenumber}]
    \normalmarginpar
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{#2}}{\marginnote{\footnotesize\sffamily [Sol~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}]}}{}
}{%
\end{Exercise}
}
%
\newenvironment{sol}{\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]}
{\end{Answer}
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{ABCD}

\begin{exo}[Shows Sol]{true}
    ABCD
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
    ABD 
\end{sol}

\begin{exo}[No Sol]{false}
    EFGH
\end{exo}
\begin{sol} % THIS WOULD NOT BE INCLUDED 
    EFG 
\end{sol}

\begin{exo}[Shows Sol]{true}
    HIJK
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
    HIJ 
\end{sol}


\section{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer

\chapter{ABCD}

\begin{exo}[No Sol]{false}
    ABCD
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}  % THIS WOULD NOT BE INCLUDED 
    ABD 
\end{sol}

\begin{exo}[Shows Sol]{true}
    EFGH
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
    EFG 
\end{sol}

\section{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379946/link-to-answer-in-exercise-package help?

Comment: I need an example in arabic this is in english

Comment: Combine it with [an Arabic template, such as this one,](https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/lua-arabic.tex) and write the parts you want in Arabic.